# How to create a scroll with many checkboxes in pysimplegui?

Tags: pysimplegui

I'm trying to create a GUI with PySimpleGUI that contains many checkboxes with a scroll to the right to it that allows me to move around. I want my GUI to maintain its size by many checkboxes that have.

This is my code:

```
form = sg.FlexForm("Dynamic Combo")
layout = [[sg.Text('<-- Enlazar Clientes con Páginas web -->')],
    [sg.Text('Dominio: ')], [sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('URL del Cliente: (con http:// o https://)')], [sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Button("SELECCIONAR TODOS")], 
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Checkbox("something")], [sg.Checkbox("something")],
    [sg.Text('')],
    [sg.Submit('Ejecutar'), sg.Cancel('Salir')]
]

form = sg.Window('Enlazador de Páginas Web').Layout(layout)
```

How can I do it? I've heard that sg.Column allows me something similar, but I've tried to implement it and I have not achieved anything.

Comment: A big problem with SO is that answers here become outdated. PySimpleGUI has evolved considerably. Using the names you see on this page are not PEP8 compliant and are no longer recommended.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that you can place the layout inside of a [Column Element](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/#column-element) in order to get scroll bars.

Try changing your last line of code to this.  It will make your window smaller and add scrollbars.  Read more on the parameters available to the Column element.

```
form = sg.Window('Enlazador de Páginas Web').Layout([[sg.Column(layout, size=(300,300), scrollable=True)]])
form.Read()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. it has helped me to get what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code now that I have made the corrections and improvements. I hope it serves you:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg, sys

form = sg.FlexForm("Dynamic Combo")
col = [[sg.Checkbox("something1",key=1)], [sg.Checkbox("something2",key=2)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something3",key=3)], [sg.Checkbox("something4",key=4)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something5",key=5)], [sg.Checkbox("something6",key=6)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something7",key=7)], [sg.Checkbox("something8",key=8)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something9",key=9)], [sg.Checkbox("something10",key=10)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something11",key=11)], [sg.Checkbox("something12",key=12)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something13",key=13)], [sg.Checkbox("something14",key=14)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something15",key=15)], [sg.Checkbox("something16",key=16)],
    [sg.Checkbox("something17",key=17)], [sg.Checkbox("something18",key=18)]]
layout = [[sg.Text('<-- Scroll with Checkbox -->')],
    [sg.Button("SELECT ALL")], [sg.Button("DESELECT ALL")], 
    [sg.Column(col, size=(300,300), scrollable=True)],
    [sg.Cancel('Exit')]
]

form = sg.Window('Checkbox practice').Layout(layout)

while True:
    event, values = form.Read()
    if event == "SELECT ALL":  
        # IN THE RANGE ALWAYS PUT A NUMBER MORE TO GET THAT NUMBER
        for x in range(1,19):
            form.FindElement(x).Update(True)
    if event == "DESELECT ALL":  
         # IN THE RANGE ALWAYS PUT A NUMBER MORE TO GET THAT NUMBER
        for x in range(1,19):
            form.FindElement(x).Update(False)
    if event == "Exit":
        sys.exit()
```

I thought that if I had a single button to select and deselect everything, and that its name would change depending on what I press would be a good idea. I am studying it, although I have not found it yet. If someone knows that you comment, please. If I learn to do it I will upload the answer. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question you've posted as part of this answer.  Feel free to post questions about PySimpleGUI on the project's GitHub site.